# Android repository-pattern & RxJava: Use Flowable or Single?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Recently, I´ve read about how important it is to have a Single-Source-Of-Truth (SSOT) when designing an app´s backend (repository, not server-side-backend). https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

By developing a news-feed app (using the awesome https://newsapi.org/) I am trying to learn more about app architecture.
However, I am unsure of how to design the repository interface for my app. 
Btw.: I am using MVVM for my presentation layer. The View subscribes to the ViewModel´s LiveData. The ViewModel subscribes to RxJava streams.

So I came up with 2 approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
interface NewsFeedRepository {
        fun loadFeed(): Flowable<List<Article>>
        fun refreshFeed(): Completable
        fun loadMore(): Completable
    }

interface SearchArticleRepository {
    fun searchArticles(sources: List<NewsSource>? = null, query: String? = null): Flowable<List<Article>>
    fun moreArticles(): Completable
}

interface BookmarkRepository {
    fun getBookmarkedArticles(): Flowable<List<Article>>
    fun bookmarkArticle(id: String): Completable
}
```

This approach is primarily using Flowables which emit data if the corresponding data in the underlying SSOT (database) changes (e.g old data gets replaced with fresh data from API, more data was loaded from API, ...). However, I am unsure if using a Flowable for `SearchArticleRepository#searchArticles(...)` makes sense. As it is like some request/response thing, where maybe a Single might me be more intuitive.

**Approach 2:**

```
interface NewsFeedRepository {
    fun loadFeed(): Single<List<Article>>
    fun refreshFeed(): Single<List<Article>>
    fun loadMore(): Single<List<Article>>
}

interface SearchArticleRepository {
    fun searchArticles(sources: List<NewsSource>? = null, query: String? = null): Single<List<Article>>
    fun moreArticles(): Single<List<Article>>​
}

interface BookmarkRepository {
    fun getBookmarkedArticles(): Single<List<Article>>
    fun bookmarkArticle(id: String): Single<Article> // Returns the article that was modified. Articles are immutable. ​
}
```

This approach is using Singles instead of Flowables. This seems very intuitive but if the data in the SSOT changes, no changes will be emitted. Instead, a call to the repository has to be made again. Another aspect to take into account is that the ViewModel may have to manage its own state. 
Let´s take the `FeedViewModel` for example (pseudo-code).

```
class FeedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // Variables, Boilerplate, ...
    val newsFeed: LiveData<List<Article>>
    private val articles = mutableListOf<Article>()

    fun loadNewsFeed() {
        // ...
        repository.loadFeed()
                   //...
                   // On success, clear the feed and append the loaded articles.
                  .subscribe({articles.clear(); articles.addAll(it)})
        // ...
    } 

    fun loadMore() {
        // ...
        repository.loadMore()
                   //...
                   // On success, append the newly loaded articles to the feed.
                  .subscribe({articles.addAll(it)}) 
        // ...
    }
}
```

So this might not be crucial for a smaller app like mine, but it definitely can get a problem for a larger app (see state management: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/arch-components-purist).

Finally, I wanted to know **which approach to take** and why. **Are there any best-practices?** I know many of you have already done some larger software-projects/apps and it would be really awesome if some of you could share some knowledge with me and others.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather go for the first approach using `Observable`s instead of `Flowable`s in your case:

```
interface NewsFeedRepository {
    fun loadFeed(): Observable<List<Article>>
    fun refreshFeed(): Completable
    fun loadMore(): Completable
}

interface SearchArticleRepository {
    fun searchArticles(sources: List<NewsSource>? = null, query: String? = null): Observable<List<Article>>
    fun moreArticles(): Completable
}

interface BookmarkRepository {
    fun getBookmarkedArticles(): Observable<List<Article>>
    fun bookmarkArticle(id: String): Completable
}
```

I don't see any reason you should necessarily use `Flowable` for this purpose since you'll never have any OOME related issues checking your repository changes. In other words, for your use case IMHO backpressure is not necessary at all.

Check [this official guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#observable-and-flowable) which gives us an advice of when to a `Flowable` over an `Observable`.

On the other hand, and not related to the question itself, I have serious doubts of what's the purpose of `loadMore` or `moreArticles` methods since they return a `Completable`. Without knowing the context, it may seem you could either refactor the method name by a better name or change the return type if they do what they seem to do by the name.

Comment: Yeah, as you might have guessed I´ve recently started learning RxJava 2 so I appreciate your advice on using Observable instead of Flowable. Regarding your doubts: `loadMore` attempts to fetch more feed articles from the API and then insert them into the DB which will trigger the Observable from `loadFeed` thus causing the view to re-render. If that process failed the Completable will fail (view shows error).   `moreArticles` works basically the same and requests more articles from API (paging). However, I am unsure on how to solve this differently? Any recommendations?

Comment: My thinking process: When the user scrolls down the feed recycler-view, a `ScrollListener` triggers `FeedViewModel#loadMore` which calls `FeedRepository#loadMore`. If it succeeds, the view will automagically (described in above comment) display the additional data. If loading more feed data failed, the View can show an error and render a retry-button at the bottom of the recycler-view. Without this Completable: How would I know if loading more feed data succeeded or failed?

Comment: We're going to another point here which should be better to be tackled in another question following StackOverflow rules. Anyway, even though you mix API and DB backend calls in the repository, the call should be clear of what it's doing. `loadMore` in my opinion shouldn't just invoke the API and then depending of that call storage trigger any other thing.That responsibility should be taken in another point, and the API should return feeds from API or DB. Check this clean architecture design patterns guides: https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture `UserDataRepository.java` class

Comment: So so you mean the repository itself should use some kind of abstraction-api that takes care of syncing network api and db? 
Anyway, I'm going to create a new question regarding this problem. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first approach is better, Your repo will update the data whenever the data is changed and your view model will be notified automatically and that's cool, while in your second approach you have to call the repo again and that's not really reactive programming.

Also, assume that the data can be changed by something rather than load more event from the view, like when new data added to the server, or some other part of the app changes the data, Now in the first approach again you get the data automatically while for the second your not even know about the changed data and you don't know when to call the method again.

Comment: Ok, I´ve already assumed this would be the better approach. But how about refreshing the feed or loading more feed data? Do you believe a Completable is appropriate for that? Or are there different ways of solving this?